# Culture-conversion in C# with DateTime

Tags: sql, datetime, culture

I'm having trouble getting my ASPX-App to work on the productive server. As my local environment is german but the server is english and my whole code didn't provide culture-support, I'm currently implementing that throughout the script.

As you might think, as I'm writing this in here, it doesn't quite work the way I want it to.

The App uses a MSSQL-Database for gathering information that is based on dateranges. So, I use the user-selected daterange for calculation using `Date BETWEEN x AND y`.

The dates are set by the user and parsed in the script to datetime-values to be able to handle them:

```
_DateRangeStart = DateTime.Parse(DateStart + " 00:00:00", _Culture);
_DateRangeEnd = DateTime.Parse(DateEnd + " 23:59:59", _Culture);
```

Where `_Culture` is defined as following:

```
public CultureInfo _Culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");
```

and `_DateRangeStart` (and `End`) are the user-input from text-fields.

So, as I look into the skript, it shows me that the user input is transformed from `1.11.2009` (which is a correct german formatted date) to `11/1/2009 00:00:00 AM`, which should be `1.11.2009 00:00:00` (for _DateRangeStart).

This value cannot be read by the SQL and it gives me an error that converting a char to a valid datetime was not possible.

Why is the conversion not done correctly?

Comment: How are you passing the dates to the script?

Comment: As I said, the user inputs them in a textfield and they are then parsed in the script. The user inputs the dates as `dd.MM.YYYY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you are calling ToString() on your DateTime variable and it's outputting in the default format. SQL then tries to interpret it in it's default format and fails. I think what you need to do is format the date in an unambiguous format and send it to SQL Server.

E.g.

```
  string myDate = _DateRangeStart.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Agree with this - in general I think it's best-practice to use non-ambiguous time formats for communication between apps. You never know when someone will set up a server with the wrong culture settings.

Comment: It worked fine that way, but for my understanding: What do you mean by "ambigous" - I know what the word means but don't see how to connect that with DateTimes?

Comment: By ambiguous, I mean when faced with '11/11/2009', you don't know whether it's day/month (British/German?) or month/day (American). 2009/11/11 is considered unambiguous as it always follows year/month/day.

Answer (score 0):

Is your sql server set to another culture than de-de ?  That would also create this behavior. If your sql server thinks he's an american he wants american formatted dates.

Comment: I don't think so, when I look into the table definition it says "datetime" as row-type and the format looks like "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss" - so I assume it's a german format.